# Optimized Nodejs code to find anagrams of a string within the array. Solution should not use all subsets to find anagram of string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to store pair of anagrams in the array.

Input will be the array.

Example:

```
let inputArray = ["abcd", "dbac", "adfs", "adsf", "bDca"];
```

It should ignore the case of the letters. Here "abcd and bDca" are anagrams.

output should be an array containing pair of anagrams.

```
Example: [
  'abcd is anagram of dbac',
  'adfs is anagram of adsf',
  'abcd is anagram of bDca'
]
```

Comment: so when you say `optimized` show us the code you've with you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned, finding all the subsets and then finding the anagrams is not optimized solution.
We can use hashmap and some inbuilt methods in node.js.
Sort each string within the array so that comparing for the anagram will be easy.
Store sorted string to hashmap. If, there is a key existing with same string, that will be the anagram.
Here is the complete solution in Node.js

```
let inputArray = ["abcd", "dbac", "adfs", "adsf", "bDca"];
let map = {};
let outputArray = [];
inputArray.forEach((anaString, index) => {
    let sortedString = anaString.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
    if (map[sortedString] != null) {
        outputArray.push(sortedString + " is anagram of " + anaString);
    }
    else {
        map[sortedString] = index;
    }
});
console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: I have seen many solutions using lot of lines of code to implement this. This solution is great and helped me to understand. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently solved a problem similar to that in java 8, which I can easily translate into javascript for you.

The naive way to do this is to loop through every possibility and then loop through the array to see if anything matches. However this would be extremely slow. To overcome this we can create a "pattern" and match it with others as we move along the array.

The following code should solve your problem

```js
function pattern(str){
   let map = new Map()
   let curcount = 0
   let pattern = ""
   for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
       if(!map.get(str.charAt(i)+'')){
           pattern+=String.fromCharCode(curcount);
           map.put(str.charAt(i)+"",String.fromCharCode(curcount));
           curcount++;
       }
       else{
           pattern+=map.get(str.charAt(i)+"");
       }
   }
}
```

The rest is very easy to do, make another map (key is pattern, value is array of strings) and record each instance of a pattern, if it exists, pop the word into the array. and you'll be set :)